# Is combination of 1+4 GB memory fine?

Tags: laptop, memory

Having a [Lenovo 3000 N200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenovo_3000#Notebooks) notebook I decided to upgrade my memory from 2×1 GB to at least 4 GB.

Due to an advice from a friend of mine I almost picked up 2×2 GB memory for like a hundred bucks, and I'd be good to go.

But, after visiting some webshops I came to the conclusion it'd be a better idea to purchase one 4 GB memory and replace only one of the old ones.

So I'd end up with 25% more memory for a little less money.

Is this combination safe? Is there anything I should consider? (I am already running x64, no need to remind me about that.)

Comment: i recently bought 4x2GB DDR2 on craigslist for $50 total, so it pays to shop around. pricewatch is good too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **Lenovo 3000 N200** has two memory slots.

Each memory slot can hold [DDR2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM) PC2-6400 or DDR2 PC2-5300 with a **maximum of 2 GB per slot**.

So, you will only waste your money on a 4 GB chip.

[More information from crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=3000%20N200%20Series%20%28All%20Types%29)

Comment: Good lookin' out on that one.

Comment: Molly brings up a valid point on the maximum slot size, you might end up with only 2GB of the 4GB usable, and therefore only have 3GB total in the end. Not the 5GB you wanted, also make sure to account for what OS you would be using, as a 32bit OS will not address more than ~3.4GB.

Comment: Many times the documentation is wrong.  It may have been written before larger SODIMMs were available, and they *might* allow access to all the RAM.  Or, it might only access 2GB.  Or, it might (fairly uncommon, but I've seen it happen before) refuse to use any of it.

Comment: your 'many times', Brian, does not include the gazillion of netbooks out there, 4 GB modules simply don't work, 'despite' the bloody documentation saying, they wont. :) if you're of the experimental type and got some money to waste, then go ahead and do it. from me, however, you will only get sound advice and that is: go and get 2x2GB DDR2 PC2-6400 and all is well. happy christmas.

Comment: oh, and you can downvote all you want but please have the decency to tell us why. if you have contrary information that 4 GB chips work well in a Lenovo N200, then your input is highly appreciated. if you just downvote for the fun of it, well, then this behaviour sheds some light on your character. or shall we say, the lack thereof?

Comment: @Molly, I appreciate your research and detailed answer, but remotely evaluating your fellow superusers is not truly valued. Happy christmas.

Comment: neither do i value anonymous downvotes. this little thing called courtesy goes a long way, i even leave a comment with many of my upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to not mismatch memory due to potential for decreased performance. However, it is completely safe and will not cause damage to the computer.

Comment: May result in system crashes though.  My desktop system, when running graphics intensive games on the internal video, will occasionally crash if in single-channel mode, but with matching RAM and dual-channel enabled it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

2 x 2GB will run in dual-channel mode, and it will be slightly faster. So if most of your use is the time, you have less than 4GB of RAM used, the 2x2GB of RAM will be a better option. On the other hand, if you frequently max out 4GB of RAM, the 4+1GB may be a better option. IIRC, some motherboards require RAM to run in dual-channel mode, so you might want to check with your manufacturer.

Comment: Some machines (commonly laptops) don't support dual-channel at all anyways.